# $\phi(f) = 0$ on all positive functionals implies $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question, but i don't know for sure if it's true.

If $E$ is a partially ordered normed vector space, and $E^*$ the norm-dual. ($E$ is a Riesz-space).

Let $f\in E$. What if $\phi(f)=0$ for all positive linear functionals, does this imply 
that $f=0$?. I know that $\phi(f)=0$ for all $\phi\in E^*$ implies $f=0$.

Also, where does this follow from? I thought it was the Hahn-Banach theorem, but i'm not sure. I just remember this last statement as a fact.